# jmeter distributed testing slave finishes before schedule

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, distributed-testing

i have a jmeter distributed system with 1 master and 4 slaves.

the test is configured to run for 60 minutes.
somehow suddenly a random slave finish the test and the load is distributed between the other 3.
all the slaves configured the same way.

the instances are aws ec2 instances on the same subnet

is there any explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reason for it:

1. Possibly load balancing was not happening properly, more sets of request are getting drived toward one instance. That can cause the VM to crash
2. **OR** It could be the crashed AWS instance. The disk space got full.

I suggest you check the disk usage of crashed vm.

Comment: the ec2 instances are not crashing, they are totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case you configured JMeter to stop thread when the error occurs yourself:

   [image]

   if you have marked settings under [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) it might be the case the Threads (virtual users) are being stopped or the whole test gets stopped on error
2. If unexpected error occurs there should be a corresponding entry in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), make sure to execute JMeter slave process providing log file location via `-j` command-line argument like:

   ```
    ./jmeter -s -j jmeter-slave.log .....
   ```
3. It might be the case your [JMeter instance runs out of memory](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) and the whole JVM gets terminated so make sure to properly tune it for high loads
4. Check operating system log of your Amazon instance

Comment: 1. i have not configured thread to stop when there are errors. 2. i will check the log, have not looked at it. 3. the instances are not run out of memory

Comment: i tried to restrict the use to just 1 slave from the master. it seems that the problem is because the slow communication between the nodes. the average RPS shows 3-4 requests per second but when runs locally the RPS is 700. is there anything i can do?